# How do I handle application security? using ActionFilterAttribute and/or SiteMap authorization..?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, security, sitemap

i created the following `ActionFilterAttribute` to check if a user is granted access to a page. I also created two custom `Exceptions` to handle different scenarios: `NotLoggedInException` and `InsufficientPrivilegeException`.

**ActionFilterAttribute**

```
Public Class ValidateAuthentication : Inherits ActionFilterAttribute
    Private _page As BLL.Page

    Public Sub New(ByVal Page As BLL.Page)
        Me._page = Page
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(ByVal filterContext As System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext)
        Select Case Me._page.IsAccessibleToUser(filterContext.HttpContext.User)
            Case -1
                Throw New NotLoggedInException()
            Case 0
                Throw New InsufficientPrivilegeException()
            Case 1
                //access granted
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

I also have a custom SiteMapProvider where I implemented my own IsAccessibleToUser() function. So I also have securityTrimming.

**SiteMapProvider**

```
Public Overrides Function IsAccessibleToUser(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext, ByVal node As System.Web.SiteMapNode) As Boolean
    Dim p As New BLL.Page
    p.LoadFromSiteMapNode(node)


    Select case p.IsAccessibleToUser(context.User)
        Case 1
            Return true
        Case else
            Return false
    End Select
End Function
```

---

***The questions:***

1. Where do I catch the exceptions to for instance redirect users if not authorized?
2. Should I perhaps use the SiteMap authorization somewhere else instead of using the ActionFilterAttribute and throwing Exceptions..?

*note: as you can see I'm using a custom class for BLL.Page. This is a ORM page which has Role based security stored in the database. SiteMap is also populated based on this data*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not reinvent `AuthoriazeAttribute`. Your version won't handle cached actions; the built in `AuthorizeAttribute` will. [If you need to customize your authentication, then customize the membership provider or subtype `AuthorizeAttribute`](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/09/09/38390/), rather than reinventing MVC security.

Comment: But i think I should be using the default Membership / Role providers. I have a custom part which defines allowed Pages for the default RoleProvider roles. I need to hook this custom part up with the default authentication but I have no idea on what to implement/where this should go...?

Comment: Be aware that Microsoft already has AzMan/AuthorizationManager which can map groups to roles. That said, if it won't work for you, you can subtype `AuthorizeAttribute` and override `AuthorizeCore`. Be *very* aware that your code here must be (1) fast and (2) thread-safe. Read the comments in the MVC source. But I'd probably pick AzMan instead.

Comment: I think i can go with AzMan. However I'm not able to find any easy implementations around on the web... Isn't there quite a bit of work involved here?

Comment: sidenote: I need the User (creation) / Page (creation) / Role (management: authorization to pages) in a webbased admin solution... So I'd like to avoid having to use servertools, windows users etc..

Comment: For AzMan there's a role provider for ASP.NET which should "just work" with MVC. But the admin interface is a MMC snapin.

Comment: So that means I'm better off using a custom AuthorizeAttribute. Does this mean I have to add this attribute to every controller action?

Comment: You can add it to a base controller class and it will apply everywhere.